# The (very short) story of a backslash

Tags: support, comments, formatting

I just noticed that I had unfortunately inserted a backslash, in a piece of text formatted as `code` in a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357062/upload-multiple-tables-from-a-single-geopackage-file-to-postgresql-postgis#comment584269_357071).
This morning, I didn't understand why my formatting went so messy....

Then I understood it was because of this backslash that -- I imagine -- I haven't correctly escaped (I though that by being in a piece of text formatted as `code` formatted , it would be printed as a true backslash and that's it. May it be a bug? I don't think so, so I don't flag this as such, but feel free to add this tag if necessary).

I can understand that nobody want comments to be editable, me the very fist, but as I cannot edit my own comment, I wonder how I can make it more readable? If possible of course.

Concretely, I wrote : "... backslash `\`. What..." and the backslash in there has messed up (like inverting) the rest of the normal text / code.

---

More on formatting:
https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Your question here is rather vague - please [edit] your question here to be specific on what the problem is, and where (quote it in here)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to re-write your comment, you can add a new one and delete the old one.

Comments are not meant for answers, and don't allow for much formatting (which makes it difficult to comment much code).  If you have an answer, post it as an answer, or if you have a question, ask it as a question.

Moderators can edit comments (but do so rarely), so you can always flag your comment and ask for it to be edited.  I had a look at the comments on that Q&A and I'm not sure I can see exactly what you're talking about.